# How do I filter male and female separately in my data set (using r)?

Tags: r, filter

I have an excel sheet in .csv loaded into r. I want to filter my data by male vs female but when I try I can't figure it out. My column titles are Male/Female and Size (mm), so my data lists either an M or and F and a number.

I've tried saying

```
Male <- Male/Female %>% filter(M);
Male <- Male/Female %>% filter(Male/Female <= M)
```

etc. I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

[Screenshot of what my current error messages look like, along with what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xlqqw.png)

[Screenshot of the majority of the data table that I'm trying to work with and filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL078.png)

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: `Male/Female` is not a normal variable name and is typically frowned upon; but if you insist on it, you must use backticks around it to use it. I don't know what `flter` is, perhaps you mean `filter`? Tests of equality need double-equals `==`, not an assignment with single-equals `=`. When using `dplyr`, you need to specify the dataframe (`FrogData`) *somewhere*. Comparisons of strings must use actual strings such as `"M"`, needing quotes. Perhaps `filter(FrogData, `Male/Female` == "M")`?

Comment: I urge you to learn how to use `dplyr`, either through your class (I'm making an assumption) or online tutorials. I'd start with https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/, perhaps try `vignette("dplyr")`, and then look for other tidyverse-based tutorials and howtos.

Comment: @r2evans: Your second comment points to a problem far more basic than any issue appropriate to dplyr/magrittr study. This person doesn't understand basic R syntax. Needs to learn rules for a valid object name. I think dplyr's effect would be to obscure such understandings. The NSE introduced too early leaves people confused about syntactic issues in R.

Comment: I completely agree, @42-, thanks for pointing that out. Often I don't know how to say nicely that somebody's grasp of R syntax is apparently missing a few key concepts. I've read many discussions for/against the use of `dplyr` (and friends) as a gateway into R, and while I agree with some of the pro's, I think your point about NSE clouding things is salient (`data.table` too).

Answer (score 0):

Use the square bracket for row and column selection.

```
# dataframe with one column and four rows
df <- data.frame(sex = c('M', 'F', 'M', 'M'))

# filter to keep only men, keeping all columns
df[df$sex == 'M', ]
```

Output:

```
[1] M M M
Levels: F M
```

If you like dplyr/magrittr:

```
df %>%
    filter(sex == 'M')
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a reproducible example will help you get help more quickly. Here I show you how to do that with some simple data.

Create fake data:

```
library(tibble)
frogData <- tribble(
  ~`Male/Female`, ~`Size(mm)`, 
  "M", 88.1, 
  "M", 96.7,
  "F", 90.7,
  "F", 89.4
)
```

There's a couple of problems I can see in your code. First, when using dplyr syntax and piping, you need to understand what objects are going where. In this case it can be understood as:

```
`new object` <- `existing object` %>% `function`.
```

The other issue is that your raw data has nonstandard variable names that need to be wrapped in back ticks to be used in R. To make things simpler, its usually best to rename those variables. With that done, its simple to filter the data to only include male records. Note the use of `==` to test an equality statement, `=` is used to assign values (like `<-`)

```
library(dplyr)
# Rename variables
frogData <- frogData %>% 
  rename(sex = `Male/Female`, 
         size = `Size(mm)`)

# Create dataset with only males
Male <- frogData %>% 
  filter(sex == "M")
```